# React - same callback for each component in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, callback

Lets say I have a components array in my React app:

```
const deleteProject = useCallback(project => {
    // something
}, []);

return (
    projects.map(p => (
        <button onClick={() => deleteProject(p)}>Delete</button>
    );
);
```

Is there any way I could use just `deleteProject` function without wrapping it into separate callbacks i.e. `{} => {}` for each component? This is for performance purposes. I mean something like:

```
 <button onClick={deleteProject}>Delete</button>
```

And then in `deleteProject` somehow I'd need to determine which project to delete, but how? It only takes click event as argument

Comment: What's the reason for this? Are you trying to pre-empt performance issues?

Comment: You could add `data-project-id` to the delete button, and on the onClick you can identify the project by `e.target.dataset.peojectId`

Comment: @naortor - That could work, thanks. For this particular case I need a whole object, not just ids, to prompt some data to user.

Comment: after you get the id, you can use projects.find(p => p.id === id) to get the whole object

Answer (score 0):

If you have a long projects list and see performance issues you could define DeleteButton component to avoid button re-rendering

```
const DeleteButton = ({project, deleteProject}) => {
    const onClick = useCallback(
        () => deleteProject(project),
        [project, deleteProject],
    );
    return <button onClick={onClick}>Delete</button>
}

const YourComponent = ({projects, deleteProject}) => (
    <>
        {projects.map(project => <DeleteButton {...{project, deleteProject}}/>)
    </>
)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it create N `onClick`s (1 per instance)? This is exactly what I want to fix

Comment: It will, but onClick per instance itself is not a problem. The real problem is memory usage, performance, etc... What exactly is problem you trying to resolve

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by assigning project identifier to button as below

```
const deleteProject = event => {
    projectId = event.target.id;
    // Delete project here using id
}

return (
    projects.map(p => (
        <button id={p.id} onClick={deleteProject}>Delete</button>
    );
```